# Is it still possible to destructively modify files that you don't own under android 10/11 (api 29/30)?

Tags: android, mediastore, android-10.0, android-11, storage-access-framework

I'd like to write an app that crops/resizes photos and writes them back to shared storage in their new size but everything I've read about how SAF and mediastore works suggests that *at best* I'd only be able to write the file back with a new name. And at worst I might not be able to open the files at all if I'm not the original creator. A solution that involves triggering a SAF dialog to open the file is reasonable though I'd like to be able to just batch change all the files (photos) in a folder (say dcim). But if I have to also trigger a SAF dialog to write the file back out that's pretty yucky.

Obviously if I were to target pre-10 versions of android this could still be done, but then I'd be blocked from the playstore, and I don't really want to write apps that *only* I can use.

Answer (score 0):

> everything I've read about how SAF and mediastore works suggests that at best I'd only be able to write the file back with a new name

Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` (or `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`). You have full read-write access to the content identified by the `Uri` that you receive.

> A solution that involves triggering a SAF dialog to open the file is reasonable though I'd like to be able to just batch change all the files (photos) in a folder (say dcim)

Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` (or `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree`). You have full read-write access to all of the documents inside of that tree.

Comment: I thought ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE was blocked for a lot of those pre-defined directories (downloads, dcim, etc).  And youre sure you have access to files you didn't create afterworlds? When you say full read-write access, do you mean the File Api, SAF, or media store?

Comment: @AlRo: "I thought ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE was blocked for a lot of those pre-defined directories (downloads, dcim, etc)" -- you get what you get. "When you say full read-write access, do you mean the File Api, SAF, or media store?" -- `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` are part of the Storage Access Framework (SAF).

Comment: I'm willing to use any API that doesn't constantly open up a file chooser dialog (once to get permissions is ok), but I certainly prefer the File API for it's simplicity and familiarity.

Comment: @AlRo: You do not have filesystem write access to the vast majority of external storage on Android 11+, including pretty much everything that you seem to be interested in. Your choices are SAF or `MediaStore`. `MediaStore` lets you create your own image-selection UI, but the way that you get write access is a bit strange. SAF can give you long-term permissions, but the device controls the selection UI.

Comment: @AlRo: I have 14 blog posts covering SAF and `MediaStore`, starting with [this one](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html). You can also see an example of `MediaStore` [here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-r/-/tree/master/VideoTagger), covered in [this book](https://commonsware.com/R).

Comment: Your comments seem to walk back the statement in your answer that you have full read-write access. Can you clarify what you mean by full read-write?

Comment: I see no walking back and full read-write access is read-write access.

Comment: @AlRo: "Your comments seem to walk back the statement in your answer that you have full read-write access" -- not really. Through the SAF, you have read-write access. Through **filesystem APIs** (what you referred to as "the File API"), you do not, to most of external storage, on Android 11+.